# how to install package under (as) peerDependencies?

Tags: javascript, npm

I'm building a library and trying to understand how to install/specify a dependency under peerDependencies.

[The npm docs don't talk about this under the command `npm install`:](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install.html)

```
npm install (with no args, in package dir)
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>
npm install <git repo url>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>

alias: npm i
common options: [-P|--save-prod|-D|--save-dev|-O|--save-optional] [-E|--save-exact] [-B|--save-bundle] [--no-save] [--dry-run]
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, there isn't a command line shortcut for installing a peer dependency. Some Googling dug up [this old issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/3994) where the npm folks briefly discussed adding that functionality, but it doesn't seem to have been made it in as of `npm@6`.

It's less-than-ideal, but I think manually editing your `package.json` file to specify peer dependencies by hand may be your best bet. As of [this 2013 blog post from the Node.js team](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/#using-peer-dependencies), that approach almost seems sanctioned:

> Peer dependencies are pretty simple to use. When writing a plugin, figure out what version of the host package you peer-depend on, and add it to your `package.json`: ...

Comment: Yeah, I get you. It means that peer-dependencies won't be installed in my local-project as well. So if I need them for testing as well, I must specify them in dev-dependencies also. Does `npm install` installs peer-dependencies if they are missing?

Comment: I don't think so; I think `npm install` will only give you a warning if a peer dependency isn't installed.